# Module 'ngRaven' not available

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, sentry, raven

I'm trying to run jasmine unit tests by including ngRaven in my code.
Below is the order of files in karma.conf.js.

```
files: ['app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
'app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
'app/bower_components/raven-js/dist/raven.js',
'app/bower_components/raven-js/plugins/angular.js'
]
```

While setting up the project I'm getting the error as

> "Module 'ngRaven' is not available! You either misspelled the module
>   name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you
>   specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Any idea as where I'm doing wrong..

I have posted the same issue in github..[click here](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/issues/529)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Fixed by adding the below dependency in bower.json

> "name": "angular-raven",   "version": "0.6.3",

and link in karma.conf.js file changed from

```
'app/bower_components/raven-js/plugins/angular.js'
```

to

```
 app/bower_components/angular-raven/angular-raven.js
```

Comment: IMHO this is not the best answer as it suggests using an unofficial bower plugin instead of the official one and it does so without warning the reader https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-raven vs https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js